# How do I get the current language in custom user edit Twig file?

Tags: 8, users

I have a custom user profile edit twig file.How can i check current language code in user twig file in drupal8?

Answer (score 0):

You can check language in twig as below:

```
{% if (language.getId() == 'en') %}
    Do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have tried this in my file.But this is not working.

Comment: Which version of D8?

Comment: @salu – What do you mean by "this is not working". Try to fix your issue strategically. So what does `{{ language.getId() }}` return you then? Did you flush your caches?

Comment: @Ajay Reddy:Am working with 8.53.

Comment: @leymannx:I have flushed the caches and no result get from {{ language.getId() }}

Comment: @leymannx:We have any hook/theme function to pass variables to user edit twig?

Comment: Simply follow the link to the duplicate question.

Comment: I have solved this by using  _context.current_language.id(here am getting the language code)